# Program linked failed -flutter

Tags: flutter

I’m writing a program using flutter and I faced a problem that shows in the console

the messages are

D/skia (17144): program linking failed

What could cause this problem?

Comment: I suggest checking the following issues reported: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22568 and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23810.

You may be able to find more with a quick google.

Comment: The first link that ITJsoctt posted: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22568 has a solution by editing launch.json for vscode. That worked for me. Haven't figured out the underlying cause though.

Comment: Try manually uninstalling your app from the (virtual) device. Then try debugging again.